# Trouble loading value from NSDictionary (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I'm having a problem reading a value from an NSDictionary. Here is my setup:

```
NSArray *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kMyConstant];
for(id value in data)
{
    NSString *stringValue = [value stringForKey:kMyValueConstant];  // This is where the error is
}
```

However, when it hits the commented line I get the following error:

```
2011-12-19 13:54:45.466 MyApp[12587:f803] -[__NSCFDictionary stringForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6898f70
2011-12-19 13:54:45.468 MyApp[12587:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary stringForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6898f70'
```

I really don't understand where the issue is occurring. Here is the code I use to set up the NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// Create the NSDictionary to hold all of the data
NSMutableDictionary *appDefaults = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

// Create a couple of samples
NSMutableDictionary *sampleOne = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[sampleOne setValue:@"Value A" forKey:kMyValueConstant];
NSMutableDictionary *sampleTwo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[sampleTwo setValue:@"Value B" forKey:kMyValueConstant];
NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:sampleOne, sampleTwo, nil];
[appDefaults setValue:list forKey:kMyConstant];


[defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: NSLog both `data` and `value`, they are not what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace

```
NSString *stringValue = [value stringForKey:kMyValueConstant];
```

with

```
NSString *stringValue = [value objectForKey:kMyValueConstant];
```

Answer (score 3):

If `value` is `NSDicitonary` type, you should use this instead :

`NSString *stringValue = [[value objectForKey:kMyValueConstant] stringValue];`